# Constructor from rvalue reference to base - viable (gcc) or not (clang) - who's right

Tags: c++, gcc, return, clang, language-lawyer

Had a compliation issue recently, illustrated by this snippet:

```
struct Base
{
};

template<typename T>
struct A : Base
{
    A(){}
    A(Base&&) {}
};

A<int> foo()
{
    A<double> v;
    return v;
}


int main()
{
    auto d = foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Gcc says it's ok, but clang disagrees and says "candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'A' to 'Base &&' for 1st argument A(Base&&) {}", see for yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/Y7mwnU

Would any of the kind readers be able to help with some standardese to support either point of view?

Comment: well... you need a copy constructor, not move constructor, no?

Comment: It's a variable in local scope so it should be treated as rvalue at return, shouldn't it?

Comment: I think it shouldn't, but not 100% sure, therefore no answer - only comments.

Comment: I really suspect copy elision on gcc and that's why it compiles. `foo` returns A<int> and you are trying to return A<double>. This should have generated a type missmatch

Comment: In a simpler case the return value is treated as an rvalue: https://godbolt.org/z/qJWZ_p

Comment: @KostasRim see here: https://godbolt.org/z/MVUrBp c++14 so no fancy copy elision and -fno-elide-constructors and still works. If you try to find an overload that matches v treated as rvalue then it should be a match, no?

Comment: @ŁukaszWojakowski he compiles with c++17 which is guaranteed to copy ellide

Comment: Changing `return v;` to `return std::move(v);` makes Clang happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clang is correct here. Filed [87530](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87530).

The rule for return statements is [[class.copy.elision]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.elision#3):

> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - If the expression in a `return` statement ([stmt.return]) is a (possibly parenthesized) *id-expression* that names an object with automatic storage duration declared in the body or *parameter-declaration-clause* of the innermost enclosing function or *lambda-expression*, or
> - if the operand of a *throw-expression* is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or *catch-clause parameter*) whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost enclosing try-block (if there is one),
>
> overload resolution to select the constructor for the copy is first performed as if the object were designated by an rvalue. If the first overload resolution fails or was not performed, **or if the type of the first parameter of the selected constructor is not an rvalue reference to the object's type (possibly cv-qualified)**, overload resolution is performed again, considering the object as an lvalue. [ Note: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the constructor to be called if elision is not performed, and the selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided. — end note ]

Emphasis mine.

We meet the first bullet, we're returning an *id-expression* that names a non-volatile automatic object. So we perform overload resolution as if it were an rvalue. This overload resolution succeeds, there is a constructor that takes a `Base&&`. However, note the bolded part. The type of this parameter is **not** an rvalue reference to the object's type.

Hence, we try again consider the object as an lvalue. This overload resolution fails.

As a result, the program is ill-formed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more doubt: this wording applies as of c++17, in c++14 the paragraph started with "When the criteria for elision of a copy/move operation are met", which, as far as I can understand, refer to [class.copy]/31.1 which says "when the expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter) with the same cv-unqualified type as the function return type". Would that mean that both gcc and clang are wrong in https://godbolt.org/z/A0g8VY ? The type is not the same, after all.

Comment: @ŁukaszWojakowski The same-type requirement is for copy elision. We're not doing copy elision, we're just treating `return x;` as `return std::move(x);` in some situations. This is one of those situations, both gcc/clang correctly treat it as a move

Comment: @ŁukaszWojakowski Also as a general suggestion, with godbolt, you don't need function bodies - especially in cases where you just want to see what's called. Here is a simpler version of your example: https://godbolt.org/z/rj5e0g (*especially* try to avoid bringing in things like `<iostream>`)